# Gradle Offline Build Using Maven Repository

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, groovy

I'm attempting to setup an offline Gradle build.

I would ideally like to have all my project dependencies in an arbitrary maven repository referenced as below:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'file://PATH/TO/REPO'
    }
}
```

However, the above fails in a fresh Gradle install (no ~/.gradle cache) with the following:

```
* What went wrong
Plugin [id: PLUGINID, version: PLUGINVERSION] was not found in any of the 
following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolvee plugin artifact     'PLUGINID:PLUGINNAME:PLUGINVERSION')
    Searched in the following repositories: 
        Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

I've tried a few different ways to specify the repository, including:

1. Replacing "url..." with "flatDir { dir '/PATH/TO/REPO' }".
2. Copying all dependencies to ~/.m2 and calling mavenLocal() as the repository.

To copy dependencies from ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ into my "offline" repository, I have tried:

1. Straight copy/paste
2. A Gradle task which converts the structure as such:

   ```
   task cacheLocal(type: Copy) {
       from new File(gradle.gradleUserHomeDir, 'caches/modules-2/files-2.1')
       into '/PATH/TO/REPO'
       eachFile {
           List<String> parts = it.path.split('/')
           it.path = (parts[0] + '/' + parts[1]).replace('.','/') + '/' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[4]
       }
       includeEmptyDirs = false
    }
   ```

Other things:

- Running with "--offline" makes no difference.
- Build is successful if ~/.gradle is already present, but fails otherwise.

My plugins block (the above error statement will hit the first non-Gradle core plugin, so protobuf in this case):

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.6"
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "4.9.3"
    id "java"
    id "eclipse"
}
```

This is out of my depth and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `repositories` block, but with the `plugins` block. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: @lu.koerfer I've added the plugins block above. From what I understand it seems like Gradle is trying to reach a network to download the protobuf plugin despite running in --offline mode and with the plugin already present in a local offline repository (I'd guess it's not picking it up, but unsure of how I'd check where the failure occurs). Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want also plugins to be resolved from a local repository, you have to configure the `pluginManagement` section to do so.
In your question, it looks like you only configured project repositories.

See the [example in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_resolution_rules)

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware that there was a separation.